# WaitAll() Not Performing as Expected

Tags: c#-4.0, task

I have written the following mocked up code as a sample of what I am seeing.  I would expect the tasks to complete in a little over a second since they all wait for one second.  Instead it takes about 41 seconds for the tasks to complete.  Why is it completing in 41 seconds and not the expected ~1 second?

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[1000];
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // allocate room in the list for the items we are going to insert
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
    tasks[i] = task;
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan span = endTime - startTime;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your tasks is pushed into the thread pool, but that is not the same thing as giving each task it's own thread and running it immediately. The thread pool does not use an unlimited number of threads, because you don't have an unlimited number of CPU cores. Running 1000 threads all at the same time would typically be *slower*, because of all the context switches as the many threads contend for the few available cores.

Instead, the thread pool tries to pick an optimum number of threads to balance between keeping everything moving and not having too many context switches, so that you get the best possible (or at least very good) throughput. 1000 tasks that each run for 1 second divided by ~40 seconds means you have 25 threads in the pool.

In this case, you could probably safely run with a much higher threadcount, because all each task does is sleep. But the threadpool doesn't know that. It's expecting you want to do actual real work in the CPU with those tasks, and was designed accordingly. Even here, keep in mind that even with just 25 threads you already have a full second's worth of overhead.

Finally, I often run across code that uses multiple threads like this to try to divide up work on the CPU, where it turns out the real bottleneck is disk or network I/O. It's always worth reminding yourself that your disk is only so fast, and if you're trying to divide up work that came from a file, or network stream, or database, your CPU is probably a whole lot faster than your data source, and you may not be gaining much, if anything. That doesn't mean "stop", but it does mean you need to also take the time to measure to be sure that this extra code complexity is actually worth it.